# Does Unlocking bootloader affect network lock?

Tags: sim-unlocking, bootloader-lock

Will the bootloader unlock procedure as shown on the HTC Dev website affect my network lock?

I have an HTC Aria, which was originally SIM locked, but I got unlocked from a shop. Now, since I'm working on Android apps and HTC devices, I want to unlock my bootloader, but I'm worried that it will re-lock my device to the original carrier.

Answer (score 4):

No, the bootloader has no bearing on a SIM/network lock. The HTCdev site explicitly states this on the [bootloader unlock page](http://htcdev.com/bootloader), in fact:

> Please note that unlocking your bootloader does not mean that you will
>   be able to unlock the SIM lock. Unlocking your SIM lock is at the
>   discretion of your operator/carrier and is not part of the bootloader
>   unlocking scope.

The reverse is also true, but the main point is that the two concepts are unrelated.

Comment: Yea, I wanted to confirm for the reverse process.Thanks alot "eldarerathis"

Comment: @user981 I disagree (partly) with the reverse bit. If the SIM is locked, you cannot unlock the bootloader.

Comment: @DanB I've not seen a situation where that was the case. Have any sources that support your statement?